# Can't give VirtualBox guest OS access to host physical LPT1 port

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, printer, lpt

**Preface:**

I've just put a 64-bit Windows 10 machine (a Dell Optiplex 760) in an office to replace an old 32-bit Windows XP PC.

The PC needs to be able to print to a very old dot matrix printer - a Star LC100. No 64-bit drivers are available - only a 32-bit one. It emulates an Epson EX-800 (not XP-800). This printer is required as it prints to fabric labels that are washed. The impact of the dot-matrix means the ink does not fade.

I've tried using the Generic Text-Only driver on the host but it gives me an error and fails to print.

---

So I've installed VirtualBox and 32-bit XP on the host, which *does* have a Star LC100 driver. I'm now trying to give the guest OS access to the physical LPT1 port.

Following [this guide](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=54187), I've ran the following commands:

```
cd "c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
VBoxManage modifyvm "XP" --lptmode1 "LPT1:"
VBoxManage modifyvm "XP" --lpt1 0x378 7
```

But now when I try to start the VM, I get the following error:

```
Parallel#0 could not open 'LPT1:' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).
Parallel device 0 cannot attach to host driver (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I've also tried running CMD and VirtualBox as Administrator with the same result.

How can I give the guest XP OS access to the physical host OS LPT1 port? The port shows up on the host OS' Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

While [the linked to guide](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=54187) shows examples such as the following:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "My VM Name" --lptmode1 "LPT4:"
VBoxManage modifyvm "My VM Name" --lpt1 0x378 7
```

And the original poster then ran these commands:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "XP" --lptmode1 "LPT1:"
VBoxManage modifyvm "XP" --lpt1 0x378 7
```

It seems based on [this bug ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15872) and [this specific comment](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15872#comment:8) the command should be as follows; note how the `:` is dropped from the `--lptmode1 "LPT1"`:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "XP" --lptmode1 "LPT1"
VBoxManage modifyvm "XP" --lpt1 0x378 7
```

That said, the [original poster solved their own issue](https://superuser.com/a/1047887/167207) by switching to VMWare. But this kind of bug seems pesky enough that it is worth clarifying a solution for any VirtualBox users that might stumble across this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used VMWare Workstation Pro 12 which had GUI support for adding an LPT1 port and worked brilliantly, straight out of the box!

I chose VMWare because although Virtual PC supposedly supports LPT ports, it cannot be installed on Windows 10 as Hyper-V has replaced it; which does not have the support for LPT.